# Need to solve 555 timer frequency polynomial problem

Tags: polynomials

I am building a 555 timer square wave generator with a duty cycle of 50%.  The frequency is controlled by two resistors and one capacitor.  The formula for frequency is:

$$F = \frac{1.44}{(r_1 + 2r_2)\times C}$$

I'll be working with a varying number of frequencies. There are website calculators that can give the answers.  But I would rather know how to solve the problem myself so I won't have to keep running to the internet.

$R_1$ is standard 10 k$\Omega$. I'll be working with low frequencies so will be using relatively high capacitance - say $22$ $\mu$F. So $C = 0.000022$. And here frequency will be $3$ Hertz.

Would someone be kind enough to show me how to solve for R in following equation?

$$3 = \frac{1.44}{(10000 + 2R)\times 0.000022}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:
$$3=\frac{1.44}{(10000+2R)\times 0.000022}$$
Multiplying both sides by $(10000+2R)\times 0.000022$ gives:
$$3((10000+2R)\times 0.000022)=1.44$$
Multiplication is associative, therefore:
$$3\times 0.000022\times (10000+2R)=1.44$$
Multiplying:
$$0.000066(10000+2R)=1.44$$
Therefore, dividing both sides by $0.000066$ gives:
$$10000+2R=\frac{1.44}{0.000066}$$
All you need to do now is solve this linear equation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  kindly.

$3 = \frac{1.44}{(R_1 + 2R_2)  \times C}$

$3(R_1 + 2R_2)  \times C = \frac{1.44 }{(R_1 + 2R_2) \times C  } \times (R_1 + 2R_2) \times C$

$3(R_1 + 2R_2)  \times C = 1.44 $

$ \frac{3(R_1 + 2R_2)  \times C}{3C} = \frac{1.44}{3C} $

$ R_1 + 2R_2 =  \frac{1.44}{3C}   $

$R_1$ = 10,000 / $C$ = .000022

$10000 + 2R_2 = \frac{1.44}{3 \times .000022} $

$10000 + 2R_2= 21818$

$10000 + 2R_2 - 10000= 21818-10000$

$2R_2= 11818$

$\frac{2R_2}{2}= \frac{11818}{2}$

$R_2 = 5909$

Comment: Yes, that is done correctly!